# error accessing oracleDB with python

Tags: python, database, oracle, cx-oracle

I used Docker to run virtual Oracle DB server on my localmachine(host).

it works well when I use in on shell(bash).

however I want to make it access from python interface.

cx_Oracle(python interface for oracle) installed,

but it was not accessed on my python code(jupyter notebook).
code is so simple as below

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect("system/oracle@localhost:8080")
```

error code:

```
DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-681e47c38e7c> in <module>()
----> 1 con = cx_Oracle.connect("system/oracle@localhost:8080")

DatabaseError: ORA-12537:
```

Comment: Although there are various defaults for the 'easy connect' connect string syntax you are using, they are not that common.  You may just need to find the 'service name' of the DB and include that: `con = cx_Oracle.connect("system/oracle@localhost:8080/whateveryourservicenameis")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can use cx_Oracle.connect with the port like that. You probably can but I would check the Data Source Name ( dsn ).

---

First, try connecting without the `:8080`. If that doesn't work, try below.

---

Go into python interactive mode from the command line. `python -i`

`import cx_Oracle`

`dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn( 'localhost', '8080' )`

---

If you don't find anything with that, check out Burleson. The site is always helpful with ORA issues.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12537_tns_error.htm

And of course, I assume you already have this doc:

http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html?highlight=connect

---

Also, assuming you are following a guide, you might want to link it's url in the comments or in your original post.